# Codeigniter database issue on live server

Tags: php, codeigniter, activerecord

Hi guys I would really appreciate if you could help my with this problem I am facing with codeigniter on live server. Everything works fine on localhost however for unknown reason active record doesn’t work on live server. I am not being able to perform any type of queries and have been trying to fix it for days now. I am not getting any errors related to database connection and I am also sure that all the database configuration details are correct and also all the user privileges.

Database.php

```
$active_group = 'default';
$active_record = TRUE;

$db['default']['hostname'] = '111.11.111.111';
$db['default']['username'] = 'username';
$db['default']['password'] = 'password';
$db['default']['database'] = 'database';
$db['default']['dbdriver'] = 'mysql';
$db['default']['dbprefix'] = '';
$db['default']['pconnect'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['db_debug'] = False;
$db['default']['cache_on'] = FALSE;
$db['default']['cachedir'] = '';
$db['default']['char_set'] = 'utf8';
$db['default']['dbcollat'] = 'utf8_general_ci';
$db['default']['swap_pre'] = '';
$db['default']['autoinit'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['stricton'] = FALSE;

Example: $this->db->query("TRUNCATE TABLE test");
```

I know I am using active records correctly as it works fine on localhost just don’t seem to understand what the problem is on live server. Thank you for your time and help guys.

Comment: Where is the database hosted?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your database is hosted on the same server/shared hosting as the CI application then your host should stay as "localhost". If it is hosted elsewhere then I would check that the server hosting CI has access to the server hosting the Db

Comment: Thanks for your help. Database is hosted on same server as the web application. There is no problem in connecting with the database its just when I run a query using active records the query doesn't do anything nor gives me any errors.

Comment: Have you got error reporting on? When you say it doesnt do anything does the page take ages to load or does it literally just give you blank white screen and nothing else? If blank white screen then check index.php and make sure your error_reporting is switched on

Comment: Also what is this IP: 111.11.111.111? Have you tried with your host as "localhost"?

Comment: Yes I have error reporting on and what I mean by when the query doesn't do anything is that lets say for example I have a query using active records to get all the data from a table. The script run as expected from start to finish other than skipping the query or not doing anything at that line of code.

Comment: I used 111.11.111.111 instead of actual IP address for my host. I have also tried using the actual host name fro example https.domain.com

Comment: You will have to show the script I think as I cant see how this could occur without a db connection issue

Comment: Sure OK. So you dont need to use the public facing IP address if the app is on the same server. Have a go with localhost as your host and see if that helps. its better anyway you may have to open 3306 to the world at large if you want to use the public facing IP better to make the connection internally